# How i can redirect to another url server nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have this app allocated in **server 8088**  and another server 
http://127.0.0.1:7777/

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
   res.redirect(' '); 
});
```

How can I make it that the page http://127.0.0.1:7777/ redirects to the page http://127.0.0.1:7777/2 (from server 8088 command)

Comment: Review: fixed code formatting; tried fixing the grammar; the question is still unclear and requires further editing by the owner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`res.redirect('http://127.0.0.1:7777/2');`

You can type in any URL to redirect to.
https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.redirect

Comment: not work but now im trying with gulp